# Not Match each element of $mylist

Tags: list, powershell

I would like to list all uninstall entries and ignore some entries with a whitelist.

Listing the uninstall entries works, but I don't understand how to use `$mylist` to ignore "app1","app2","app3".

```
$mylist = @("app1","app2","app3")

Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall,
        HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
    Get-ItemProperty |
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -notmatch $mylist } |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString
```

Have you an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking if a list doesn't contain a particular element use the `-notcontains` or `-notin` operator:

```
... | Where-Object { $mylist -notcontains $_.DisplayName } | ...
```

or

```
... | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -notin $mylist } | ...
```

Note that the `-notin` operator isn't available prior to PowerShell v3.

For doing partial matches of one list against another you need something like this:

```
... | Where-Object {
    $name = $_.DisplayName;
    -not ($mylist | Where-Object {$name -like "*$_*"})
} | ...
```

Comment: Hello thanks for anwser, but I was not complete on my question, for example with the app "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable" I would insert only "Visual" and not all complete name, I try "-notlike" but it doesn't work, do you have idea ?

Comment: See updated answer. Please make sure to not leave anything relevant out of your question the next time.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but that's seem to not work after several test, 
I still have line which contains element of my list. Thanks for the time devoted to my problem

Comment: My bad. It must be `$name -like "*$_*"`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a regex pattern from the list, and then use the `-match` operator:

```
# Construct pattern
$pattern = @($mylist|ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

# Use pattern with -match
... |Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match $pattern }
```

Comment: It's work fine thank you, i never use pattern so i will look at that :) thanks you again :)